# Query ManyToMany where only 1 result on join table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a Statistiquecolle table in a ManyToMany relationship with a Groupe table.
I want to get all StatistiqueColle rows which are linked ony to the Groupe of id 1.

I'm able to select all StatistiqueColle rows linked to Groupe of id 1 but I also have rows linked to Groupe of id 1 and other groupes.

Here's my query (statistiquecolle_groupe is the link table between statistique colle and groupe) :

```
SELECT sc.id, sc.colle_id, sc.effectif, sc.moyenne, sc.mediane, sc.note100, sc.major, sc.minor
FROM statistiquecolle sc
INNER JOIN statistiquecolle_groupe scg ON sc.id = scg.statistiquecolle_id
WHERE scg.groupe_id = 1
AND sc.id = scg.statistiquecolle_id
```

I thought about counting rows in a where clause and select only StatistiqueColle rows for which there's one statistiquecolle_groupe row but I don't know how to do it.

**Edit : Table structure**
[image]

Comment: Can you upload the structure of your tables?. It would help

Comment: I've just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it in this way, i have changed the table order in the join, set a left join and remove the and clause in the where because you already had it in the ON clause:

```
SELECT sc.id, sc.colle_id, sc.effectif, sc.moyenne, sc.mediane, sc.note100, sc.major, sc.minor
FROM statistiquecolle_groupe scg 
LEFT JOIN  statistiquecolle sc ON sc.id = scg.statistiquecolle_id
WHERE scg.groupe_id = 1 AND 
      sc.id NOT IN (SELECT sc1.id
                    FROM statistiquecolle_groupe scg1 
                    LEFT JOIN  statistiquecolle sc1 ON sc1.id = scg1.statistiquecolle_id
                    WHERE scg1.groupe_id != 1)
```

Try now .Hope it works

Comment: I tried it and it returns all the StatistiqueColle rows which are linked to groupe of id 1. 

I want those which are only linked to groupe of id 1 excluding those which are linked to this groupe and one/many other(s).

Comment: Ok, i try to do it later

Comment: You have a new version, try it